# Converting an XML recordset into an HTML table in asp.net

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, .net-2.0

How can I convert an XML recordset into an HTML table in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create an asp:Literal control, use a [stylesheet transformation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322) to change from XML to HTML, and then grab the InnerXml for the Literal control's value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20010526.asp